# How to concisely put that two methods identify shared yet different results

Tags: concision

What's a very concise, pithy but formal way (register is scientific English) to say that two methods identify the same set of factors involved in a process but that **one** method identifies more factors on top of the shared results?

In essence, I want a short statement that captures the following:

> Method X and Method Y identifiy a shared set of factors; however,
>   Method X also identifies some additional factors

Comment: Your question is clear enough as it is, but it might help stimulate some ideas if you could give some example sentences, fill-in-the-blank style.

Comment: I know I asked for an example sentence, but that one simply reprises your question. Can you provide a sentence you'd like to write in your actual paper (or whatever), and show us what word(s) in that sentence you'd like us to fill in? In other words, provide a template sentence *as you'd actually want to write it*, with blanks for the sought word(s).

Comment: I guess the sentence structure that captures the quoted statement is one of the moot points. I'd want that statement to be rephrased in as concise a way as possible.

Comment: While method Y identifies some of the factors involved, method X identifies all these plus others.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I suggest you make your Comment an Answer.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock There are three reasons I contribute here. The first is to offer some information or analysis that I hope will benefit understanding of the English language and even adjust practice, amongst visitors to the site. Or to discuss such topics, where I'm undecided or unclear. I'd post this sort of contribution as an answer. The second is to address a reasonably valid (on ELU) query, with not vast potential of general usefulness to others. I'd usually put this in a _comment_. (The third is trying to outdo Erik Kowal etc in dire punning.)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "proper subset", although other terms could also apply.  Here's a summary of your choices:

1) subset relation, also called set inclusion: a derived binary relation between two sets.  If all the members of set A are also members of set B, then A is a subset of B, denoted A ⊆ B. From this definition, it is clear that a set is a subset of itself. (these use the same data pool and one can be less than the other but the problem with using this term is it won't be clear that one set contains less data than the other, since the term can mean either less than or equal data)

2) proper subset: A is called a proper subset of B if and only if A is a subset of B, but B is not a subset of A.  (clear that you mean one set has less data, and both use the same data pool).